# What is the optimal Python data structure and how to export it to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I am trying to analyze mechanical computation results using Python and export them to Excel automatically. My raw data consists of various types of computation (each stored in a different text file). For each type, I have various load cases (loading conditions). For each load case, I output the results are various datapoints. Finally, at each datapoint, I need to store one vector result (with 3 components). So basically, the general structure is:

```
computation --> load --> datapoint --> component = value
```

After searching for similar questions, for instance:

- [python: combine multiple files into a matrix with 1 and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894202/python-combine-multiple-files-into-a-matrix-with-1-and-0)
- [Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary)
- [Python: how to export a dictionary of nested lists to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334365/python-how-to-export-a-dictionary-of-nested-lists-to-excel)

and many others, it looks like the pandas library of Python seems the most appropriate, especially the [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and its ability to generate [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table) or [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html).

So far, I created a list of dictionary similar to this:

```
dd=[]
files = ["computation1.out","computation2.out"]
for files in files:
    filename=file.split(".")[0]
    with open(file,"r") as f:
        for row in f:
           ...
           #process file and extract
           #  loadnumber
           #  datapointnb
           #  component number icomp
           #  value
           # Creating a new Python dictionary
           mydict = {'Computation': filename,
                     'Load Case': RefValues[iref],
                     'Datapoint': EntValues[ient],
                     'Compo': icomp,
                     'Value': float(row)}
           # Append it to the list
           dd.append(mydict)
print(json.dumps(dd, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd)
print(df)
df.to_excel("myoutout.xlsx", sheet_name='Data', float_format="%.4f", merge_cells=False)
```

This generates something like this:

```
[
    {
        "Component": 1,
        "Computation": "computation1",
        "LoadCase": 1.0,
        "Datapoint": 57,
        "Value": 0.0004761905
    },
    {
        "Component": 2,
        "Computation": "computation1",
        "LoadCase": 1.0,
        "Datapoint": 57,
        "Value": -9.333414e-18
    },
    {
        "Component": 3,
        "Computation": "computation1",
        "LoadCase": 1.0,
        "Datapoint": 57,
        "Value": 0.0
    },
    {
        "Component": 1,
        "Computation": "computation1",
        "LoadCase": 1.0,
        "Datapoint": 84,
        "Value": 0.0009523809
    },
    ...
]
     Computation  LoadCase  Datapoint  Component         Value
0   computation1       1.0         57          1  4.761905e-04
1   computation1       1.0         57          2 -9.333414e-18
2   computation1       1.0         57          3  0.000000e+00
3   computation1       1.0         84          1  9.523809e-04
...
```

The conversion from the list of dictionaries to a dataframe and the export to Excel went well but I can't seem to create automatically pivot table or restructure the data in lines and columns:

```
           |computation1                                   |computation2...
           |-----------------------------------------------|---
           |loadcase1            |loadcase2            |...|loadcase1...
           |compo1 compo2 compo3 |compo1 compo2 compo3 |...|compo1...
-----------------------------------------------------------|---
datapoint1 |val1   val2   val3   |val4   val5   val6   |...|...
...        |...                                            |...
datapoint3 |val7   ...                                     |...
-----------------------------------------------------------|---
```

I have two questions:

- Would this data structure (list of dictionaries) be the most efficient once the amount of data gets bigger and if not, what would you recommend? I also investigated nested dictionaries but seemed more complicated to export to Excel.
- How can I restructure my dataframe to export to Excel using the appropriate format?

Thank you for you help,
Christophe

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel()`

Comment: Thank you @MattDMo. I tried this but the Excel sheet contains raw data `defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000015CC54CB130>, {'Node % 57': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,...`. I was hoping for a more structured way where my loads and datapoints would be in rows and columns. Should I rework the dataframe or use other options in the `to_excel` function?

Comment: Aside from `df.to_excel()`, there is also a `pd.ExcelWriter` class that you can use as-is with arguments, or subclass and customize as needed. You could also import `openpyxl` and use its functionality directly, or as part of your `ExcelWriter` subclass.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to restructure my data bit using a list of dictionaries instead of nested ditionaries and used df.to_excel to dump it to Excel. I edited my question to reflect this. Unfortunately, I still question the efficiency of the structure and the export to Excel is a flat list of data whereas I'd like some fields to be columns and others to be lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, converting my list of dictionaries to `pandas.DataFrame` and using the appropriate arguments to `pandas.pivot_table` and exporting to Excel using `pandas.pivot_table.to_excel` did the trick.

Full solution was those lines:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dd)
mypivot=pandas.pivot_table(df, index=EntTypeLabel, columns=['Computation',RefTypeLabel,'Compo'], values='Value')
print_dbg(1,mypivot)
myExcelfile="samres.xlsx"
mypivot.to_excel(myExcelfile, sheet_name='Data', float_format="%.4f", merge_cells=False)
```

This finally generated the desired output:

```
Computation   COMPUTATION1          COMPUTATION2         ...
Load Case   Load Case-1.00        Load Case-1.00         ...
Compo               Comp-1 Comp-2         Comp-1 Comp-2  ...
Node %                                                   ...
5559                  1.13  -1.08           0.80  -0.63  ...
5561                  0.77  -1.17           0.54  -0.68  ...
17789                 1.00  -1.17           0.66  -0.62  ...
17791                 0.69  -1.16           0.49  -0.60  ...
56690                 0.81   0.03           0.57   0.44  ...
56812                 1.01  -0.04           0.70   0.33  ...
```

Thanks to @MattDMo for the suggestion to use to_excel.